# Wordpress taxonomy terms

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

So i'm having problem understanding, how can i set correct terms for my query. Right now my query is following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $taxChild-> term_id,

        ),
    )
);
```

Currently query is looping trough category taxonomy and returns every post that is queried via url. Example: http://website.com/category/{category-name}. Everything works correctly, except when i post new blog post then it shows latest category with the posts. Query queries all the categories as a sectors not post by post like it should be. Then i discovered that i can control the tax query with terms argument, but i'm not sure how can i set it up that i queries only most recent posts not categories.

Full source code for category.php https://pastebin.com/1Rvk1b7X

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd2al.jpg

Comment: $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args);
this will result in your most recent post and then later use for each to display accordingly

Comment: Okay thanks, now it really pulls latest posts correctly, but filters stopped working and posts duplicate. When i select another category it just hides previous category posts, but looks like loop start again with each category.

Comment: Each category starts loop again and thats why there are duplicates, but im not sure how should i change my query to prevent this issue. Full source code to category.php: https://pastebin.com/GzNxWwQN

Comment: why are you passing inidvidual id using foreach , actuallywhts yur site about can yu explain what are you trying to achieve ??

Comment: Mainly my site is for blog posts, where editors can post style related posts/news. What i trying to achieve is when user is in category page then latest post is shown, not by sub-category. Currently when i use query_posts($args), then it pulls posts without dublicates but shows categories as sectores like example picture shows. When i replace query_posts with wp_get_recent_posts, then it pulls latest post, but each sub-category will start loop again and duplicates all the posts.

Comment: try using key variable to display posts related to a particular category and then use get_recent_posts

Comment: Newbie question incoming, but could you please tell me, what do you mean by key variable ($args) and how could i relate in wordpress posts with category? Thanks. :)

Comment: <li class="cat-item"><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/categories?$key=<?php echo $taxonomy->slug; ?>" title="<?php echo $taxonomy->name; ?>"><?php echo $taxonomy->name; ?><span><!-- <?php echo $taxonomy->count; ?> --></span></a></li>

this is just an exapmle of wht i ve done. here the key is taxonomy slug name so all posts related to that slug will be displayed, then use get_recent_posts();